# Get nested property name and its value from object C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an object and I want to get full primitive property path and its value.

```
Type1 Prop1
   |_ Type2 Prop 2
         |_ string Text
   |_ Type3 Prop3
         |_ Type4 Prop4
                |_ int Number
    ...
```

What I tried so far:

```
var props = obj.Prop1.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in props)
{
     var name = GetData(prop, obj);
     // add name to list/dictionary and process it
}
```

```
static bool IsPrimitive(Type t)
{
    return t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string);
}
```

```
static KeyValuePair<string,object> GetData(PropertyInfo property, object reference)
{
    if (IsPrimitive(property.PropertyType))
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(reference,null));
    }

    var props = property.PropertyType.GetProperties();
    var name = property.Name;
    object value = null;

    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        var kvp = GetData(p, reference);
        name += $".{kvp.Key}.";
        value = kvp.Value;

        if (IsPrimitive(p.PropertyType))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(name.Trim('.'), value);
}
```

The problem is that for `GetValue(reference, null)`, I get exception:

> 'Object does not match target type.'

What I'm doing wrong ? I tried:

`GetData(prop, obj);` also `GetData(prop, obj.Prop1);`, but same error

The expected output would be:

```
Prop1.Prop2.Text and its value
Prop1.Prop3.Prop4.Number and its value
```

Comment: Your expected output has two entries, yet your method is only returning one `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: Not that is important ( i have added a comment that will be added to list), i get error of GetValue method which I can't get rid off

Comment: I don't think you have thought this through. It is unclear what `GetData(prop, obj)` is expected to return. Can you describe exactly what its return value means?

Comment: for example `Prop1.Prop2.Text, "This is text"`  /  `Prop1.Prop3.Prop4.Number, 100`, I have problem getting property's value

Comment: You should pass the immediate reference to `GetValue`, that should be `obj.Prop1` in this question.

Comment: I assume those are the key value pairs that `GetData` would return? What is the `property` and `reference` parameters in each case?

Comment: @shingo I tried `GetData(prop, obj.Prop1);` but same exception

Comment: I have issue in foreach where call recursive the method with reference of main object instead of current immediate object

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for this problem:

```
public class ReflectionExperiments
{
    public static void ExtractProperties()
    {
        var room = new Room { Name = "Living room", Door = new Door { Width = 10, Length = 20 } };

        var result = new Dictionary<string, object?>();
        ExtractPrimitiveValues("Root", room, result);

        foreach (var (pathToProperty, primitiveValue) in result)
        {
            if (primitiveValue is null) Console.WriteLine($"{pathToProperty}: null");
            else Console.WriteLine($"{pathToProperty}: {primitiveValue}");
        }
    }

    private static void ExtractPrimitiveValues(string prefix, object? obj, Dictionary<string, object?> result)
    {
        var objType = obj?.GetType();
        if (objType is null || IsPrimitive(objType))
        {
            result[prefix] = obj;
            return;
        }

        foreach (var property in objType.GetProperties()) ExtractPrimitiveValues($"{prefix}.{property.Name}", property.GetValue(obj), result);
    }
    
    private static bool IsPrimitive(Type t) => t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string);
}

public class Room
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public required Door Door { get; set; }
}

public class Door
{
    public required int Width { get; set; }
    public required int Length { get; set; }
}
```

Invoking the `ExtractPRoperties` method writes on the console the following lines:

```
Root.Name: Living room
Root.Door.Width: 10
Root.Door.Length: 20
```

Of course, you can further customize this code segment for your needs. For example, you can change the way `null` values are handled.

Comment: This is very simple but I have nested one where I have issue with foreach statement where I pass main object's reference instead of immediate object, dunno how to do that

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Please actually *demonstrate* why this answer doesn't fit your needs. Show a code snippet that uses this answer's solution, show what it outputs, and show what output you wanted it to produce.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to resolve, I have read property value and pass to nested object:

```
static KeyValuePair<string, object> GetData(PropertyInfo property, object reference)
{
            if (IsPrimitive(property.PropertyType))
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(reference, null));
            }

            var props = property.PropertyType.GetProperties();
            var name = property.Name;
            object value = null;

            // added this line
            object obj = property.GetValue(reference, null);

            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                var kvp = GetData(p, obj);

                name += $".{kvp.Key}.";
                value = kvp.Value;

                if (IsPrimitive(p.PropertyType))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(name.Trim('.'), value);
}
```